# VBA- Printing to a listbox

Tags: vba, listbox

I'm writing a piece of code in VBA that imports some data, organizes it, and then prints it out in a list box.  But i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong when trying to print to the list box.  My code looks like this.

```
Private Sub cmdDisplaySchedule_Click()
    Call listSchedule
End Sub

Public Sub listSchedule()

Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To MB2Boats.Count 'MB2Boats is the class where all of my data is containted.

        SchedulerUserForm.LBoxBay2.AddItem
        SchedulerUserForm.LBoxBay2.List(i - 1, 0) = MB2Boats(i).MB2BoatName
        SchedulerUserForm.LBoxBay2.List(i - 1, 1) = MB2Boats(i).MB2Bay
        SchedulerUserForm.LBoxBay2.List(i - 1, 2) = MB2Boats(i).MB2Duration
        SchedulerUserForm.LBoxBay2.List(i - 1, 3) = MB2Boats(i).MB2Waiting
        SchedulerUserForm.LBoxBay2.List(i - 1, 4) = MB2Boats(i).MB2StandardDeviation
    Next i

End Sub
```

The above will only print the boatnames and nothing else.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I believe .List is read only. I'll look into this after lunch if you still need help

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834793.aspx

Comment: Check the `ColumnWidths` property in the VB Designer view. You can specify these programmatically if needed, but usually you should set some default column widths in the Designer.

Comment: @DavidZemens If you merely adjust the `ColumnWidths` and do not increase the `ColumnCount` then you still just get to see 1 column (default for newly created ListBoxes): for testing this you may use the example below by un-commenting the increase in `ColumnCount` and adding instead: `UserForm1.ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "20;20;20;20;20"`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe all data is loaded into the form and you just don't see it yet. Try adding this line to the end of the sub:

```
SchedulerUserForm.LBoxBay2.ColumnCount = 5
```

As an update to the comments provided here is an interesting little example (with an empty workbook an empty new UserForm1 and and empty new ListBox1 dropped into the UserForm1:

```
Public Sub ListBoxColumnTest()

Load UserForm1

UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem
UserForm1.ListBox1.List(0, 0) = "hello"
UserForm1.ListBox1.List(0, 1) = "hello"
UserForm1.ListBox1.List(0, 2) = "hello"
UserForm1.ListBox1.List(0, 3) = "hello"
UserForm1.ListBox1.List(0, 4) = "hello"

'The below message box will answer with 1
MsgBox "The current column count is: " & UserForm1.ListBox1.ColumnCount
'This will increase the column count to 5 and
'thereby only adjust the column widths (fair distribution of the give space for 5 even columns).
UserForm1.ListBox1.ColumnCount = 5

UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: Kurt specifically uploads 5 columns to the list. Why do you suggest that the column count should be <> 5? Furthermore, this solution list is merely meant to be a quick fix for Kurt. Obviously, setting the column count to 5 automatically adjusts the column width **only**. Otherwise, it would be too late the increase the column count to 5 at the end of the sub (after writing to the list). So, once the problem has been identified (not seeing the data as mentioned in the solution) I am sure that Kurt will go back to the VBE anyway and manually adjust all column width to what best fits his needs.

Comment: @DavidZemens maybe I do not understand. But maybe you haven't understood my answer yet. So, I added a small "test" to the above solution for your consideration. Note, that (in the test) you can also add another `UserForm1.ListBox1.ColumnCount = 1` and then back again `UserForm1.ListBox1.ColumnCount = 5`. The data will not get truncated. All 5 columns will still be there.

Comment: Yep you're right I was mistaken about the ListBox functionality. I thought that assigning to `.List(0, n)` would raise an index out of bounds error, unless the ListBox had previously been configured for appropriate number of columns. I've removed my comments and given +1.